# Check len(df) and remove rows if not divisible by 5

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have the following pandas dataframe with n rows (n=13 in this sample).

```
df= pd.DataFrame(index= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
df['A']= np.random.randint(1, 100, size= df.shape[0])

    A
0  24
1   4
2   99
3   70
...
13 rows × 1 column
```

I want to convert it into 5-minute binned arrays with shape (2, 5) as such:

```
df.values.reshape(len(df)//5, 5)
```

but len(df), which is equal to 13, is not divisible by 5, so this operation doesn't work.
I want to remove 3 samples from the beginning or the end of the dataframe so that the remainder of the operation len(df)//5 is 0. I can obviously do df[3:], but I am looking for a more efficient way to do this since I want to use this operation in a for loop for a bunch of files with various lengths.

So, I want to write a program that checks the length of the df and if it is not divisible by 5 remove the necessary number of rows from the dataframe so that the operation works.

How can I achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Check below:

```
num_bins = len(df) // 5

num_rows_to_remove = len(df) - (num_bins * 5)

if num_rows_to_remove > 0:
    if num_rows_to_remove < 3:
        df = df[num_rows_to_remove:]
    else:
        df = df[:-num_rows_to_remove]
```

Answer (score 1):

Find Remainder

```
remainder = len(df) % 5
```

Comment: Ohh, I can just do df[remainder:] ! Thanks, its simple enough.

Comment: Please accept my answer, if that solve your problem. Thanks